# How to compile java postgresql app with random package

Tags: java, postgresql, compilation

It might be easy question but I'm currently newbie on this stuff so forgive me If something is wrong.

I have a 'Registeration.java' and It uses postgresql.So I can compile it as :

```
$ javac -cp postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar Registeration.java
```

But I want to use this file in a package like(tree) :

```
main
    Main.java
    -> src
     Registeration.java
```

I know I can compile Registeration.java as  :

```
$ javac -d . Registeration.java
```

The things is how can combine this two thing ? I want to have classes in src directory except Main.java.

Note : I don't use Eclipse or Netbeans.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the first line of `Registration` `package src;`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the folder `main` (on Windows), you can use

```
javac -cp postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar;. src\Registeration.java  Main.java
```

For non-Windows it should look something like

```
javac -cp postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar:. src/Registeration.java  Main.java
```

Comment: I'm greatful for your attention.